# Ошибка в программе

Tags: objective-c

Выдает ошибку, говоря что корень типа double, как сделать корень целочисленным ?

```
d = b * b - 4 * a *c;

do {
    a = arc4random() % 10 + 1;
    b = arc4random() % 10 + 2;
    c = arc4random() % 10 + 3;
} while (d % sqrt(d));
```

Comment: функциональщиной попахивает :)

Comment: @nosferatume, что Вам на самом деле нужно?


Найти три целых числа 0 < a < 11, 1 < b < 12, 2 < c < 13 для которых d нацело делится на sqrt(d) ? Так?

--

Попробуйте сформулировать свою задачу на *русском языке*.

Answer (score 1):

Привести тип возвращаемого sqrt значения к int:

```
while ((int)d % (int)(sqrt(d)));
```

Если Вы хотите, чтоб алгоритм работал для целых корней без приведения (чтоб не было ситуации выхода из цикла при d = 4, например), то код стоит немного изменить. Нужно проверять не остаток от деления, а наличие дробной части у double после деления d на его корень:

```
    double e;
    int a, b, c, d;
    do {
        a = arc4random() % 10 + 1;
        b = arc4random() % 10 + 2;
        c = arc4random() % 10 + 3;
        d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    } while ((d == 0) || (modf((d / sqrt(d)), &e)));
```

Comment: https://space.zeo.net/g/17cqf

Comment: В этом мире много несправедливостей. Одна из них следующая - на ноль делить нельзя... Можно конечно создать другой тред по решению это проблемы, но я думаю, что Вы сможете обойтись без этого и проверить значение d до выполнения операции по нахождению остатка от деления.

Comment: написал 
while ((d > 0) && ((int)d % (int)(sqrt(d))));
но второе условие не проверяется

Comment: А если d< 0?  Тогда все напрасно? Луше уж:
while ((d != 0) && (d % (int)sqrt(d)))

Comment: все равнов второе условие не проверяется

Comment: Сорри, ввел Вас в заблуждение. Ночь, суббота... while повторяем пока либо d равен нулю либо d не делится без остатка на свой корень. Вот такой код у меня работает как часы

        do {
            a = arc4random() % 10 + 1;
            b = arc4random() % 10 + 2;
            c = arc4random() % 10 + 3;
            d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        } while ((d == 0) || (d % (int)sqrt(d)));

Comment: получилось что d равен восьми, как в таком случае выполняется второе условие ?

да, не так)
хотел чтобы выходило целое без приведения, то есть
9/3
81/9
25/5
16/4

Comment: Очень просто. 
d = 8
sqrt(8) = 2,82. После приведения к int это значение равно 2. Остаток от деления 8 на 2 равен нулю, выходим из while. Что не выполняется? Алгоритм работает не так, как Вы хотели?